# Editing Work Item Type in TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, alm

I'm trying to change the work flow for bugs in TFS 2013.

The default is New, Approved, Committed, Done, Removed. I would like to change this to New, Committed, Ready For Testing, Done, Rejected.

I installed Power Tools 2013 to do this, so I'm opening the bug WIT from the server and using the Workflow type. However, anytime I even rename an existing state and save, it's causing this behaviour where if I change a bug to the state I created/edited it automatically removes it from the backlog. What am I doing wrong here??

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who comes across the same issue, I worked out what was wrong. I had to import the Bug.xml and the ProcessConfiguration.xml. I had to add a state type for the states I changed/added to the ProcessConfig before I imported it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the WITD (Work Item Type Definition) XML into you project using the [witadmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) command line application.

For example:

```
witadmin importwitd /f:Bug.xml /p:MyProject /collection:http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried importing it via power tools and via witadmin, still experiencing the same thing. Example - I added in a step Ready For Testing and created transitions. If I change a bug from Committed to Ready For Testing the bug is removed from the Backlog items screen and the following is shown -

"test bug" was removed because of your recent changes.Hide details
The following changes removed the item:

State was set to: Ready For Testing
If you did not want to remove this item, you may edit it to undo your changes. Edit now